# SQL Server : ISNULL(compound NULL condition, 'a string') returns only the 1st character, under certain circumstance(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, isnull, nullif

I'm a self-taught, vaguely competent SQL user. For a view that I'm writing, I'm trying to develop a 'conditional `LEFT`' string-splitting command (presumably later to be joined by a 'conditional `RIGHT`' - whereby:

- If a string (let's call it 'haystack') contains a particular pattern (let's call it 'needle'), **it will be pruned to the left of that pattern**
- Otherwise, the entire string will be passed unaltered.

So, if our pattern is ' - ',

- 'A long string - containing the pattern' will output as 'A long string'
- 'A string without the pattern' will be returned as-is.

Rather than using the crudest ways to do this, I'm trying to come up with a way that avoids having to repeat any clause (such as if `0 < CHARINDEX`, then take `CHARINDEX` - 1, etc.) and instead leverages conditional `NULL`ing.

Yet - here's what I get for trying to be creative - I've hit what seems to be a really basic stumbling block. Please observe the following code and results, and let me know whether you can replicate it - and hence whether it's a bug or I've missed something peculiar. I have tested this on SQL Server both 2008 R2 and 2014, both Express editions.

```
select
    -- ISNULL: returns 'a big old string'
    ISNULL(null, 'a big old string'),

    -- NULLIF: returns NULL
    left(
        'a big old string',
        nullif
        (
            CHARINDEX
            (
                'needle',
                'haystack'
            ), 0
        ) - 1
    ),

    -- combined: returns just 'a' (1st character of ISNULL condition)
    ISNULL(
        left
        (
            'a big old string', -- the input string. In reality, this would be a column alias, etc.
            nullif
            (
                CHARINDEX       -- Search for the splitting pattern
                (
                    'needle',
                    'haystack'
                ), 0            -- If it's not found, return NULL instead of the usual 0
            ) - 1               -- so that this subtraction produces a NULL, not an invalid negative index
        ),
        'a big old string'      -- If the pattern was not found, we should return the input unaltered
    );

/*
---------------- ---- ----
a big old string NULL a

(1 row(s) affected)
*/
```

Why do these 2 clauses work as expected in isolation, but **when I combine them, rather than getting the sum of their effects, I get only the 1st character** of the `ISNULL` string - 'a'?

Is there some kind of implicit `CAST` to `varchar(1)`? Deliberately `cast`ing to `varchar(max)` made no difference. What else could be going on here?

Am I just doing something really stupid? Because from here, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and so it really seems like a bug. I hoped testing on 2014 would prove it to be a bug in the old 2008 R2, but alas, they act identically (or, rather, don't).

Thanks in advance for, hopefully, saving me from what would presumably be an evening of baffled existential crisis.

Comment: Not sure the answer to the question "why do these 2 clauses work when you don't combine them," but, this should work: `SELECT SUBSTRING(@stringToSearch, 0, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@searchString, @stringToSearch), 0), LEN(@stringToSearch) + 1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this problem, the first is the nature of the `ISNULL` operator, it will use the datatype and length of the first argument. A simple example would be:

```
DECLARE @A CHAR(1) = NULL,
        @B VARCHAR(MAX) =  'This is a test';

SELECT TOP 1 Test = ISNULL(@A, @B);
```

This returns `T` and checking the execution plan XML we can see the implicit conversion of `"This is a Test"` to `CHAR(1)`:

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="isnull([@A],CONVERT_IMPLICIT(char(1),[@B],0))">
    <Intrinsic FunctionName="isnull">
    <ScalarOperator>
        <Identifier>
        <ColumnReference Column="@A" />
        </Identifier>
    </ScalarOperator>
    <ScalarOperator>
        <Convert DataType="char" Length="1" Style="0" Implicit="true">
        <ScalarOperator>
            <Identifier>
            <ColumnReference Column="@B" />
            </Identifier>
        </ScalarOperator>
        </Convert>
    </ScalarOperator>
    </Intrinsic>
</ScalarOperator>
```

Your example is not quite so straightforward since you don't have your types nicely defined like above, but if we do define the dataypes:

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(MAX) =  'a big old string',
        @B VARCHAR(MAX) = 'needle',
        @C VARCHAR(MAX) = 'haystack';

SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(LEFT(@A, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@B, @C), 0) - 1), @A);
```

We get the result as expected. So something else is happening under the hood. The query plan does not delve into the inner workings of the constant evaluation, but the following demonstrates what is happening:

```
SELECT  Test = LEFT('a big old string', NULLIF(CHARINDEX('needle', 'haystack'), 0) - 1)
INTO    #T;

SELECT  t.name, c.max_length
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns AS c
        INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
            ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
            AND t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE   [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T');

----------------
name        max_length
varchar     1
```

Basically, by using the `SELECT INTO` sytax with your left expression shows that a when the NULL length is passed to `LEFT` the resulting datatype is `VARCHAR(1)`, **however**, this is not always the case. If I simply hard code `NULL` into the `LEFT` function:

```
SELECT  Test = LEFT('a big old string', NULL)
INTO    #T;

--------------------
name        max_length
varchar     16
```

Then you get the length of the string passed, but a case expression that should be optimised away to the same thing, yields a length of 1 again:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 Test = LEFT('a big old string', CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
INTO    #T;

----------------
name        max_length
varchar     1
```

I suspect it is related to the default behaviour of `VARCHAR`, where the default length is 1, e.g:

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR = 'This is a Test';

SELECT  Value = @A,                                         -- T
        MaxLength = SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@A, 'MaxLength')   -- 1
```

But I can't tell you why you would see different behaviour for `NULL` and `CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END`. If you wanted to get the bottom of what is going on in the constant evaluation I think you would probably need to re-ask on the DBA site and hope that one of the real SQL Server Gurus picks it up.

In summary, `LEFT(<constant>, <constant expression>)` where `<constant expression>` yields `NULL` is implicitly typed as `VARCHAR(1)`, and this implicit type is used in `ISNULL` evaluation.

For what it is worth, if you explicitly type the result of your `LEFT` function then you get the expected result:

```
SELECT ISNULL(
            CAST(
                LEFT(
                    'a big old string', 
                    NULLIF(CHARINDEX('needle', 'haystack'), 0) - 1
                    ) 
                AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                , 'a big old string');
```

---

An additional point is that when you say you don't want to repeat any expressions (If 0 < CHARINDEX, then take CHARINDEX - 1, etc.), there are two things you should know, the first is that `NULLIF(<expression>, <value>)` expands to a case expression - `CASE WHEN <expression> = <value> THEN NULL ELSE <expression> END`, so  is repeated, the second is that this doesn't matter, SQL Server can identify that this is the same expression used twice, and will evaluate it once and refer to the same result each time it is used.

Comment: Splendid. Thanks a tonne for your help! I might indeed ask on DBA to get a bit more 'behind the scenes' info; it depends how geeky I end up feeling tonight. :-) Cheers!

Comment: Note to self: Start plotting execution plans! I run traces all the time to figure out what other programs are doing and sense-check my own, but I have never actually looked at them pre-execute. So in addition to a great answer, this is great advice.

Answer (score 5):

This is the difference between `isnull` and `coalesce` -- and since your first parameter to isnull is char(1), that will be the type of return value of the statement. With coalesce you'll get the correct result.

[Isnull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

Returns the same type as check_expression. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the replacement_value. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression and no replacement_value is provided, returns an int.

[Coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as nonnullable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @GarethD wins for explaining _why_ my "first parameter to isnull is char(1)", however!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you are over complicating a simple thing.

This sql code should do what you describe:

```
Declare @SomeString varchar(max) = 'asdf asdf - cvbncvbn',
        @Needle varchar(100) = '-'


DECLARE @NeedlePattern varchar(102) = '%' + @Needle + '%'

SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX(@NeedlePattern, @SomeString) > 0 THEN
         LEFT(@SomeString, PATINDEX(@NeedlePattern, @SomeString) - LEN(@NeedlePattern)+1)
       ELSE
         @SomeString
       END
```

[See sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1767)

Comment: "over complicating" or just a fun thought-exercise - as mentioned in my OP, I was looking for something that would allow me to avoid repeating clauses. I'm not claiming this matters in terms of the query optimiser or anything like that, but it was just something I wanted to design. It's already taught me a couple of new tricks and traps, so I'd say it was worth it!